# I want to make a video go fullscreen automatically after it begins

Tags: html, fullscreen

I don't know if there is a way to make a video go fullscreen simply by pressing the play button. My boss asked me to do so with a video on a client site. We are aware that they can push the fullscreen button manually but we want to see if we can put in a command that can auto fullscreen just by pressing play or if the video autoplayed it would detect the audio and go fullscreen.

Comment: Doing this is a good way to ensure I leave and never return to that website.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specs defined in HTML5 to make a video fullscreen, but there is a [Fullscreen API](http://www.w3.org/TR/fullscreen/) that defines a `requestFullScreen` method which allows videos (and other elements) to be made fullscreen.

It is now [supported in most modern desktop browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen).

**[Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)**

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```